# UFW not denying traffic on specific ports

Tags: ufw

I have setup a UFW to allow all incoming and outgoing traffic by default.  I wish to limit a few ports (in this case, 9200 and 5601).  When I have the following configuration:

```
> sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
9200                       DENY IN     Anywhere
5601                       DENY IN     Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
9200 (v6)                  DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
5601 (v6)                  DENY IN     Anywhere (v6)
```

I still seem to be able to access ports 9200 and 5601 from the outside world.  What's going on?

Comment: which version of ubuntu ?

Comment: can you give the output of  `sudo iptables-save  | grep -i -e input -e skip.*policy.*input `

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, Output from `iptables-save` command can be found at https://femto.pw/e8zd.txt

Comment: can you run the same with `sudo iptables-save  -c | ` ....

Comment: With the `-c` argument provided: https://femto.pw/rtc9.txt

Comment: can you give more information about the context of this host ? how many interfaces ? this is acting as a router ?

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful for you. Follow the instruction

Start and enable UFWs `systemd` unit:

```
sudo systemctl start ufw
sudo systemctl enable ufw
```

Deny Incoming in 9200 and 5601

```
sudo ufw deny in 9200 | sudo ufw deny in 9200/tcp | sudo ufw deny in 9200/udp
sudo ufw deny in 5601 | sudo ufw deny in 5601/tcp | sudo ufw deny in 5601/udp
```

If you want to turn off UFW completely and delete all the rules, you can use `reset` command:

```
ufw reset
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the config file with `nano` or `vi`

```
sudo nano /etc/default/ufw
```

make sure IPV6 is set to yes

```
IPV6=yes
```

restart `ufw`

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

I hope that helps.